# How to Get Tapped Item from Tapped Event in StackPanel

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listpicker

I have a ListPicker in an application page, but the SelectionChanged event gets called multiple times as the page loads. To avoid this, I have been following a previous question I asked here [ListPicker SelectionChanged Event Called Multiple Times During Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592301/listpicker-selectionchanged-event-called-multiple-times-during-navigation) in which the suggestion was instead of making ThemeListPicker_SelectionChanged make a parent stackpanel inside the datatemplate..', create a tap event in the StackPanel called `stk_Tap`, and 'use this tap stk_Tap to do your action as, this event would also get called every time the selection changed gets called but, it wont exhibit the buggy behavior like that of selection changed event'

Now I have adjusted my solution accordingly, but I do not know how to determine which item of the ListPicker is being selected or is currently selected. Also I removed the ListPicker SelectionChanged event in the ListPicker because I thought the StackPanel could get the item, but I am not sure if this is correct or how to do this?

XAML

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ThemeListPicker" Header="Theme"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}" 
                SelectionChanged="ThemeListPicker_SelectionChanged"/>
```

XAML.CS

```
private void ThemeListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender,
                                          SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if(ThemeListPicker.SelectedIndex != -1)
   {
       var theme = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem;

       if (index == 0)
       {
          Settings.LightTheme.Value = true;
          MessageBox.Show("light");
       }
       else
       {
           Settings.LightTheme.Value = false;
           MessageBox.Show("dark");
       }
   }                            
}
```

*EDIT: How I updated my solution

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate"> 
           <StackPanel tap="stk_Tap"> 
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/> 
            </StackPanel> 
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ThemeListPicker" Header="Theme"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}" 
                />
```

So, even when I left the ListPicker SelectionChanged event in the code behind after making the modifications, I did not see the event being called twice upon the page loading/navigating to, but I am not sure how to get the currently selected item now?

EDIT2**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        themeList = new List<TestApp.Common.Theme>();
        themeList.Add(new TestApp.Common.Theme() { Name = "Darker", name = "dark" });
        themeList.Add(new TestApp.Common.Theme() { Name = "Lighter", name = "light" });
        ThemeListPicker.ItemsSource = themeList;
    }

private void stk_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ThemeListPicker.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            //Need to get the current ThemeListPicker's 'name'
            var selectedItem1 = (sender as StackPanel).DataContext as ListPicker;

            //use selectedItem1

        }
    }
```

Comment: well, you might also be getting the value SelectedIndex with the tap event.

Answer (score 0):

No need to extra tap event for such kind of work.

```
private void ThemeListPicker_SelectionChanged(object sender,
                                          SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if(ThemeListPicker.SelectedIndex==-1)
           return;
       var theme = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem;
       if (index == 0)
       {
          Settings.LightTheme.Value = true;
          MessageBox.Show("light");
       }
       else
       {
           Settings.LightTheme.Value = false;
           MessageBox.Show("dark");
       } 
       ThemeListPicker.SelectedIndex=-1                              
}
```

ListPicker SelectionChanged Event Called Multiple Times During Navigation
 for above problem if i guess right you set listpicker's itemssource on OnNavigatedTo event. so modify you r onNavigatedTo method with

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back)
            {
            // Your code goes here
            }
        }
```

//Stack panel tap event

```
private void stack_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
   {
    var selectedIrem = (Cast as your type)(sender as StackPanel).DataContext;
   }
```

Comment: Ok I will certainly try this. The thing is, I have MainPage, and then the ThemeListPicker is on a SettingsPage that is NavigatedTo from MainPage. So is setting `e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back` applicable? How is setting that statement going to prevent `ThemeListPicker_SelectionChanged from firing twice when SettingsPage is NavigateTo? Also, would another option be to just set ThemeListPicker's ItemsSource in the SettingsPage Loaded event?

Comment: @Matthew whenever you set item source of  ThemeListPicker, selectionchanged event will fire. There are no way to restrict it. So i will suggest you do your work on any other event and remove selectionchanged event

Comment: Ok. I have removed the ThemeListPicker_SelectionChanged event as shown in my edit above. I was thinking to use the StackPanel Tap event to get the currently selected item in the ListPicker. My question though is exactly that, how might I get the currently selected item in the ThemeListPicker from the StackPanel Tap event?

Comment: @Matthew edit ans please give a look it works for me

Comment: For some reason in my Edit2 where I added `var selectedItem1 = (sender as StackPanel).DataContext as ListPicker;` the `selectedItem1` = null although when placing my cursor over DataContext while debugging I can see the current item of the ListPicker?